# Android custom title. How to follow the system theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I use below method to create a custom title.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);

}
```

title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, the system title follows the theme, title text color follow the theme too.(Example: the color is blue) But my custom title text color is not blue. I can't fix my text color, because the theme can change.
How does my custom title color follow the system theme? 
The system theme is defined by Sony.

Comment: You could try setting the `TextView`'s style to `?android:attr/windowTitleStyle` to apply the system's current theme style. By the way, depending on what you actually want to customize, you potentially don't have to create your own layout for the title bar. In stead, customize the 'window title'-related attributes in your app's theme.

Comment: Thank you! It (?android:attr/windowTitleStyle) works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the `TextView`'s style to `?android:attr/windowTitleStyle` to apply the system's current theme style. By the way, depending on what you actually want to customize, you potentially don't have to create your own layout for the title bar. In stead, customize the 'window title'-related attributes in your app's theme.